# JQuery Update Options From Json Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have this HTML form:

```
<select name="finder[4]" id="finder-2--4" class="pffield pf-make">
   <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
   <option value="52505">Alfa Romeo</option>
   <option value="52506">Audi</option>
   <option value="52499">BMW</option>
   <option value="52501">Ford</option>
</select>
```

I have this jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("document").ready(function(){
        //console.log('on load');
    jQuery(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
        //console.log('post');
    var data = {
    "action": "test"
    };
    data = jQuery(this).serialize() + "&" + jQuery.param(data);
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/reglookup.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data['make']);

            //$(".pf-make option:selected").text("Ford");
            //$(".pf-make option:contains(Ford)").attr('selected', true);
            //$(".pf-make option[text=" + data["make"] +"]").attr("selected","selected");
            $(".pf-make").val('52499');
            alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["make"]);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

I get the following return from the json post

```
Object {make: "Ford", model: "Focus", year: "2010", engine: 2.5, fuel: "Petrol"}
```

So the post and call back work fine as these get logged in the console, and I need to be able to take the called back make data["make"] and update the selected option in the select form.

You can see I have tried a number of different options, even hand typing "Ford" into the code, but I always seem to get the following error back in the console:

```
(index):221 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null
```

For the life of me I cant get this working at the moment.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky - I'm not sure what you mean here, I'm not great at jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the option value using `contains`, then set the select:-

```js
var ford = $('.pf-make option:contains("Ford")').val();

$('.pf-make').val(ford);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="finder[4]" id="finder-2--4" class="pffield pf-make">
   <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
   <option value="52505">Alfa Romeo</option>
   <option value="52506">Audi</option>
   <option value="52499">BMW</option>
   <option value="52501">Ford</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in jQuery 1.7? I am still getting (index):218 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null with your code inserted - but I can see it working in your example with 2.2.1

Comment: Ahh sussed it - jQuery instead of $

Comment: Use caution with this answer. There may be a potential XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @MrCode for my future knowledge, how is it a XSS vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$` use `jQuery`, and also use Instead of `data["make"]` to `data.make`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to iterate over the options to find the matching text, then access its value.

```
var $select = jQuery('.pf-make');
var value = 0;
$select.find('option').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).text() == data.make){
        value = jQuery(this).val();
        return false;
    }
});
$select.val(value);
```

Comment: what about `$(this).selected = true;` instead of `value = $(this).val();`?

Answer (score 0):

see this updated code. Please take note that it uses **ID** rather than **class name** to make it more specific

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("document").ready(function(){
        //console.log('on load');
    jQuery(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
        //console.log('post');
    var data = {
    "action": "test"
    };
    data = jQuery(this).serialize() + "&" + jQuery.param(data);
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/reglookup.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
    data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#finder-2--4").val(data.make);
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This method would assume that data.make is the ID of the option wouldn't it?